# Do there exist materials whose Opacity varies with temperature?

Tags: visible-light, temperature, material-science, laser, optical-materials

Do there exist materials whose Opacity varies with temperature?
E.g a Material that becomes more Opaque as it gets hotter?

Comment: Are you looking for a reversible effect?

Comment: Are you asking for solid materials or gases/liquids? Certainly in liquids and gases there are all sorts of nonlinear, complex opacity behaviour that would fit your bill... Solids are just.. not opaque?

Comment: Solids. A normally transparent Solid.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly materials which change colour with temperature. This behaviour is called [thermochromism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermochromism).

Answer (score 0):

> a Material that becomes more Opaque as it gets hotter?

Many meats and other proteins exhibit this property

Salmon:
[image: from “ explore.typhur.com/how-to-tell-if-salmon-is-cooked”]

Other fish:
[image: from “www.beyondsalmon.com/2005/10/is-it-done.html?m=1”]

Chicken:
[image: from “www.today.com/food/woody-chicken-breast-t258881”]

But perhaps the best example is egg whites:
[image: from “phys.org/news/2021-03-egg-x-ray-peek-cook.html”]

Now, I think I will go eat.